# Graph coloring problem: add colors to edges

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, graph-coloring

I'm using networkx to implement the edge coloring algorithm

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from ([1,2,3,4,5])

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(1,5)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(4,2)
G.add_edge(3,1)
G.add_edge(5,4)
G.add_edge(3,5)

# list of nodes
U = list(G.nodes)

# variable with number of edges
K = G.number_of_edges()
Z = []

# creating a set of available colors. We assume that K = {0, 1, . . . , K − 1}and K ≤ |E|
def nrofCol():
Z.clear()
z = 0
while z < K - 1:
    Z.append(z)
    z = z+1
return Z
```

now i have to add a variable to each edge that represents the color. Each edge should have all the available colors as follows:

```
G[u][v][z] = 1,2,0

G[u][v][z] = 1,2,1
G[u][v][z] = 1,2,2
G[u][v][z] = 1,2,3
G[u][v][z] = 1,2,4
G[u][v][z] = 1,2,5
G[u][v][z] = 1,2,6
G[u][v][z] = 1,4,0
G[u][v][z] = 1,4,1
......
where u and v are nodes and z is the color
```

i tried with:

```
for u,v in G.edges():
for z in Z:
    G[u][v]['color'] = z
```

but only one color to each edge is added. A better solution?

Comment: I don't know the module, but how can one line have multiple colours at once? E.g. what are you expecting?
With what you are doing right now, you overwrite the colour for each edge and the resulting colour is the last colour in Z

Comment: there is a binary variable where the used color will have value = 1 and all the other color value = 0

Comment: can you be more precise about your representation? I think you want an edge attribute, e.g. "possible_colors" which is a list of all the possible colors this edge can adopt, and the possibilities will be changed/reduced as you solve the problem? But it is hard to tell if that is what you are trying to do, esp from the big list of G[u][v][z] entries.